# Saving ByteBuffers to file give empty file

Tags: java, nio, java-io

I'm trying to save ByteBuffers to a file:

```
        FileChannel fc = new FileOutputStream("file.something").getChannel();

        while(true) {
            ByteBuffer b = nalUnits.poll();

            System.out.println("gonna write " + b.capacity());
            //printByteBuffer(b);
            fc.write(b);
        }
        System.out.println("gonna close");
        fc.close();
        System.out.println("did close");


static void printByteBuffer(ByteBuffer b) {
    for (int k = 0; k < b.position(); k++) {
        System.out.print(b.get(k) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I get this as output:

```
gonna write 41091
gonna write 41498
gonna write 41299
gonna write 40836
gonna write 40275
gonna write 40708
...
gonna close
did close
```

but the file has 0kb. If I uncomment "printBuffer", I can see all the buffers printed on screen, they're not empty. Why do I end up with an empty file?

Comment: Looks like you need to call `force()` on the `FileChannel` - see [Is FileChannel#force is equivalent to OutputStream#flush? Do I always have to call it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34859380/is-filechannelforce-is-equivalent-to-outputstreamflush-do-i-always-have-to-ca)

Comment: @SirRaffleBuffle `((FileChannel) fc).force(true);` didnt work. Putting `false` also didnt work

Comment: You need to flip before write, and compact afterwards. See the Javadoc.